# Sort by custom field using Jira's API

Tags: php, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am trying to use Jira's API to get back data.  Everything works fine unless I try to sort by a custom field.  If I sort by a default field, it's fine, but if I sort by a custom field, I get this error:

```
 {"errorMessages":["Not able to sort using field 'customfield_11200'."],"errors":{}}
```

Here is the API call:

```
search?jql=project+IN+(TEST)+order+by+customfield_11200+asc&fields=id,key,priority,summary,issuetype,status,customfield_11100,customfield_11200&maxResults=3&startAt=0
```

Any ideas on why you can't sort on a custom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, it turns out that Jira's api expects the field to be formatted like this: cf[11200]